# Python Bottle Notifications

Tags: jquery, python, bottle

I have a webinterface that runs on bottle.py.
What I wan't to do is pop up a small notification on the website if certain things happen.

I'm not sure of how to tell the client that something happend.

Should I just poll for it or is there a more elegant way ?

Since I want the notifications to appear in a timely manner i would have to poll at least every second and that sounds like a lot of load for the webserver just for notifications.

Comment: You could look at web sockets. Other than that you would have to poll

Comment: That does look exactly like what I was searching for...Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by Joe Doherty, websockets is a solution. You may be ineterested by [bottle-tornadosocket](https://github.com/cime/bottle-tornadosocket) in order to run bottle on top of the [Tornado web server](http://www.tornadoweb.org/). I didn't try myself but it looks interesting.

However, websocket may not be available for all browsers. Using long-polling is another solution. In this case, I would recommend to look at [tornadio](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio) which should be possible to use together with bottle.

I hope it helps